# No entity was found matching the key with GAE Java

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to get an Entity directly from the DatastoreService using the id. So this is my code:

```
Key repairKey=KeyFactory.createKey("Repair",Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ID")));

Entity repair=        datastore.get(repairKey);
```

The result is this message:

> com.google.appengine.api.datastore.EntityNotFoundException: No entity was found matching the key: Repair(336)

But it is impossible because this entity with this ID exists in the DB.

How can i fix it?

Comment: The code seems to be correct. I've just tried it with my entities and it works without any problems. Doesn't your entity have a parent?

Comment: I resolved with your question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Entity repair have a parent entity, so i correct with this code:

```
Key keycar= KeyFactory.stringToKey(request.getParameter("keycar"));
    Key repairKey= KeyFactory.createKey(keycar,"Repair", Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("ID")));
```